# EventObject is not defined when calling a class function out of mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a Object which "manages" a <div>-Element. I wanted it to do something on mousemove so I wrote this line in a function I call to create the content of this -Element:

```
$('#' + this.slider_id).mousemove(this.mouseMoveHandler(e));
```

Later i defined a function which handles this Event:

```
this.mouseMoveHandler = function (e) {
    var mouseX = e.pageX;
    ....
}
```

But when I call it, all I get is :

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't invoke the function, but pass a function reference: `$('#' + this.slider_id).mousemove(this.mouseMoveHandler);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rob mentioned... you're actually invoking your function, with some unknown variable `e`.  You should be passing a reference to the function itself, which will then get invoked when the event happens, passing along the event object.

So to fix all that, just do this:

```
$('#' + this.slider_id).mousemove(this.mouseMoveHandler);
```

Comment: thanks, but I have a follow-up question: I declared some Object variables like this:
   `$.slider = function() {
 this.pct = new Array();`
but when I try to call them in my mouseMoveHandler, those variables are undefined. Is this function called in another Scope?

Comment: Found the solution:
I have to call `this.mouseMoveHandler` with `$.proxy(this.mouseMoveHandler,this)`